# Why do my dependencies of a dependency conflict when installing in composer-php?

Tags: php, package, composer-php

I am running `composer install` inside a directory with the following `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name" : "Sprout Setup",
    "description" : "Allows the easy set up of a WordPress website",
    "autoload" : {
        "files": [],
        "psr-4" : {
        "SproutSetup\\": "SproutSetup/"
        }
    },
    "require" : {
        "sproutwp/sprout_services" : "*@dev"
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following errors:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Installation request for sproutwp/sprout_services *@dev -> satisfiable by sproutwp/sprout_services[dev-master].
    - sproutwp/sprout_services dev-master requires sproutwp/sprout_interfaces *@dev -> satisfiable by sproutwp/sprout_interfaces[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

The packages' github repos:

https://github.com/sproutwp/sprout_services

https://github.com/sproutwp/sprout_interfaces

https://github.com/sproutwp/sprout_privileges

As you can see, I require that `sprout_services` make use of `sprout_interfaces|sprout_privileges` with any kind of `*dev` version, yet it still says it's not matching the requirements.

**I'm inclined to think that I need to declare a** `minimum-stability` **flag**, if that's the case, then why?

Answer (score 0):

You must declare a `minimum-stability` flag in the `composer.json` where you're running `composer install` on:

```
"minimum-stability" : "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```